# How to set WinDateTimePicker to actual Date in C#

Tags: c#, datetimepicker, vs-unit-testing-framework

I am working on UnitTests using C#. Recording a Test Case, a WinDateTimePicker was recognized.

I want to set the time as the same as it is **now**, plus twenty minutes (which I dont think it should give me any trouble).

I tried to solve it using this code:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
string actualTime= dt.ToString("hh:mm");
uIReagendedWDtp.DateTimeAsString = actualTime;
```

Also I tried this:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
uIReagendedWDtp.DateTime = dt;
```

In both cases I got this exception

```
 Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. Parameter name: value
```

What could be the cause of this? How do you think I could set time as I want it?

PD: Just to help you see how things are working, I have to say this did work:

```
uIReagendedWDtp.DateTime = uIReagendedWDtp.DateTime.AddMinutes(20);
```

But it doesnt solve the problem completely

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your string `actualTime` will only have the current time of day. When parsed into a Datetime object, the default date of 0001/01/01 will be used. This may cause a problem for you. Try using `dt.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm")` or whatever format you use... By the way, why didn't the second method you provided solve the problem completely, it seems like the correct way to do it...

Comment: You mean the last code line I wrote? It doesnt solve it because the thing missing is setting Date to what it is now.

Comment: Oops, I just realized with the answer posted that you didn't actually do `DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(20)`, which is the correct way to do it :)

Answer (score 3):

How about doing

uIReagendedWDtp.DateTime = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(20);

Comment: Is the ulReagendedWDtp.DateTime a DateTime type? Do you get the error on the line with the ulReagendedWDtp.DateTime when you run the test in debug mode?

Comment: Yes, it is a DateTime type. And the error ocurrs on that line everytime except on the last code line I wrote at de PD

Comment: Can you provide the whole code for your UnitTest? What is the value of the ulReagendedWDtp.DateTime before you try to assign a new value? How is the ulReagendedWDtp object created?